# JPA call a Stored Procedure in database that contains multiple out parameters

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, stored-procedures, jpa

I have a store procedure in database which contains multiple OUT parameters. I want to use JPA (with Hibernate) to get the resultset. Is there any way to get all results from the OUT parameters?

E.g. When using CallableStatement you can use ".registerOutParameter" for those parameters. I want the equivalent for JPA (if exists/possible).

Database used is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Try to search for "jpa stored procedure **CallableStatement**" (not CollableStatement) here on SO. Many good answers!

Answer (score 1):

JPA2.1 will have StoredProcedure support as you require (not yet final). The only JPA implementation that provides a preview feature of this AFAIK is [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/stored_procedures.html). Other JPA impls may have their own non-standard support, so check your manual if wanting to go that route

Answer (score 1):

This explanation is based on Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate.

1. Define a `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` for your stored procedure in the `Example` entity class as below. In this example the stored procedure is assumed to have `IN`, `INOUT` and `OUT` type parameters each.

   ```java
   @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
       @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
           name = "Example.myStoredProcedure",
           procedureName = "db.MY_STORED_PRODEDURE",
           parameters = {
               @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "pInParam", type = String.class),
               @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "pOutParam", type = Date.class),
               @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.INOUT, name = "pInOutParam", type = Integer.class),
           }
       )
   })
   @Entity
   public class Example {
       @Id
       Integer id;

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Define a method in the `ExampleRepository` class with only the `IN` and `INOUT` parameters of stored procedure. Set the values of the parameters `procedureName` and `value` of `@Procedure` correctly. The return type of this method should always be `Map<String, ?>`.

   ```java
   @Repository
   public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Integer> {
          @Procedure(value = "Example.myStoredProcedure", procedureName = "db.MY_STORED_PRODEDURE")
           Map<String, ?> executeMyStoredProcedure(@Param("pInParam") String pInParam, @Param("pInOutParam") String pInOutParam);

   }
   ```
3. Call the above defined method in the `ExampleService` class as below. You can now retrieve multiple `OUT` values (`INOUT`s too) from `Map<String, ?>` returned by the method using the `@StoredProcedureParameter` names defined in step 1.

   ```java
   @Service
   public Class ExampleService {
      final ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

      public ExampleService(ExampleRepository exampleRepository) {
          this.exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
      }

      public void executeMyStoredProcedure(String someString, Integer someInteger) {
          Map<String, ?> result = exampleRepository.executeMyStoredProcedure(someString, someInteger);

          Date dateValue = (Date) result.get("pOutParam");
          Integer integerValue = (Integer) result.get("pInOutParam");

          ...

      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

here you can easily call stored procedure from spring data JPA repository by implementing custom repository..

1. Create a interface and define your method.
2. create impl for it annotate with @Repository
3. under method implementation below is the way ti implement

   ```
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Your Stored Procedure name");

   // Set the parameters of the stored procedure.
   String firstParam = "first param name";
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(firstParam, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
   storedProcedure.setParameter(firstParam, first Param value);

   // Set the second parameters of the stored procedure.
   String secondParam = "second parameter name";
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(secondParam, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
   storedProcedure.setParameter(secondParam, "second paramter value);

   //Your OUT parameters.
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("First OUT parameter name", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("OUT second parameter name", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
   storedProcedure.execute();
   //Replace MyObject with your actual POJO
   MyObject myObject= new MyObject();
   myObject.setFirstParameterOutput((Integer) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("first OUT parameter name"));
   myObject.setSecondParameterOutput((Integer) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("second OUT parameter name"));
   return MyObject;
   ```

Note: Noe even you can call from Repository itself by annotate @Procedure

```
@Procedure
public Integer procedure_name(String firstParameter, Date secondParameter);

 }
```